# Multiple overflow warnings when using scipy.integrate.quad, minimize and derivative

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to solve a physical problem with python. The goal is to find the a_n values that minimize the function epsilon (see image):

[image]

And the code is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from scipy.misc import derivative


def TryN(x, an, N):
    out = 0
    for n in range(N+1):
        out += an[n]*(1-x)**(N-n+1)*(x+1)**(n+1)
    return out


def Bracket(f, g):
    dot = lambda x: f(x)*g(x)
    return quad(dot, -1, 1)[0]


def Energy(an, N):
    phip = lambda x: TryN(x, an, N)
    norm = np.sqrt(Bracket(phip, phip))
    phip2 = lambda x: derivative(phip, x, n = 2)
    energy = Bracket(phip, phip2)
    return energy/norm


N = 1
an = [1]*(N+1)
af = minimize(lambda a: Energy(a, N), an, method = 'Powell', tol = 1e-8).x
print(Energy(af, N))
```

But the result is:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\Abel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 2366
    if (w - xc) * (xb - w) > 0.0:
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\Abel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 2382
    elif (w - wlim)*(wlim - xc) >= 0.0:
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\Abel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py", line 2361
    w = xb - ((xb - xc) * tmp2 - (xb - xa) * tmp1) / denom
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "E:/Sync1/Estudios/Universidad/Grado en Física/3º Grado en Física/Mecanica_Cuantica_II/Practicas/Practica2/P22.py", line 17
    dot = lambda x: f(x)*g(x)
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "E:/Sync1/Estudios/Universidad/Grado en Física/3º Grado en Física/Mecanica_Cuantica_II/Practicas/Practica2/P22.py", line 18
    return quad(dot, -1, 1)[0]
IntegrationWarning: The occurrence of roundoff error is detected, which prevents 
  the requested tolerance from being achieved.  The error may be 
  underestimated.
nan
```

I think that the problem is related with derivative, but I don't find the error. The result of `print(Energy(af, N))` should be a positive number and the function phi_p is similar to a sine function, their aproximation depends on N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks fine. I think that you should try different parameters and methods depending on your problem.
For example, trying with other methods than Powell you will get no warnings (e.g. `method="L-BFGS-B"`), but the minimized energy becomes negative.

Therefore, since the energy must be a positive number, you can try to use a different method than `Powell` that allows a constraint.
In your case, `lambda a: Energy(a, N)` must be greater or equal to zero.

Try to change:

`af = minimize(lambda a: Energy(a, N), an, method = 'Powell', tol = 1e-8).x`

into:

`af = minimize(lambda a: Energy(a, N), an, method = "COBYLA",
 tol = 1e-8,constraints={"type": "ineq", "fun": lambda a: Energy(a, N)}).x`

Using your code with this change I get

`af = [2.54114168e-11, -3.57836680e-10]`

`Energy(ag, n) = -1.4143692851366237e-09`

Using higher N (better approximation for phi), e.g. N = 4:

`af = [0.07193712, 1.24003014, 0.38689775, 1.14349888, 0.26623006]`

`Energy(ag, n) = -4.9576111873203776e-08`

If this makes sense, depends on your problem. I suggest you to read through the documentation for [minimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) and [derivative](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.derivative.html) and try different combinations and parameters. 
For example, you can try to give a smaller spacing in the derivative to achieve a higher precision.

Comment: There was a problem with some parameters in the code, I corrected them and the scipy functions work well.